# PLS-00488: object "string" must be a type or subtype - but it is a type

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c, user-defined-types

I am trying to do build a sentence using a UDT, as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE fv_group as object(
fv NUMBER,
group_number INTEGER
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE fv_group_array IS VARRAY(100) OF fv_group;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE fv_grouping AS OBJECT (
 fv_and_group fv_group_array,
 MEMBER PROCEDURE insert_groupby(FV NUMBER),
 MEMBER FUNCTION which_group(FV NUMBER) RETURN INTEGER
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY fv_grouping as
 MEMBER PROCEDURE insert_groupby(FV NUMBER) IS
    g fv_group;
BEGIN
    IF fv < 15 THEN
        g := fv_group(fv,1);
    ELSE
        g := fv_group(fv,2);
    END IF;
            fv_and_group.extend(1);
        fv_and_group(fv_and_group.last) := g;
END;
MEMBER FUNCTION which_group(FV NUMBER) RETURN INTEGER IS
feature NUMBER;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..fv_and_group.count LOOP
        feature := fv_and_group(i).fv;
        IF  fv_and_group(i).fv = fv THEN
            RETURN fv_and_group(i).group_number;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN 0;
END;
END;
/
```

The representation I need is:

```
DECLARE
     obj fv_grouping;
BEGIN

 SELECT :obj.which_group(gb.fv), count(*)
 FROM (
   SELECT :obj.insert_groupby(c.fv, 6, 3)
   from  cophir
   ) gb
   GROUP BY :obj.which_group(gb.fv);

END; 
/
```

The procedure insert_groupby inserts each value of the **cophir** table into a varray, which holds its values and the corresponding group.
After the varray is loaded with all values and their corresponding group, I want to group them. Is it possible, to do it in a query?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: in your example `insert_groupby` has only 2 parameters, but you pass 3 values

Comment: @hotfix - true but that's not the cause of the PLS-00488 error.

Comment: even if the type with the name `grouping` is allowed, it causes the future issues as being a keyword as @APC emphasized. The Database primarily assumes it as a keyword instead of being a type. I suppose it's a bug, and should be fixed for Oracle DB( the issue still exists for version 12.1.0.2.0 ).

Comment: Indeed, there is a issue ... I'd like to use the type in the query ... is it possible by any means?

Answer (score 3):

> grouping is a type. What is wrong?

GROUPING is [an Oracle keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions080.htm#SQLRF00647). If you re-name your type to say FV_GROUPING you will solve the PLS-00488. Which will leave you free to address all the other syntax errors in your code:

1. The object type is not instantiated correctly in the query.
2. SELECT statements embedded in PL/SQL must select into a variable which matches the projection of the query.

Not sure what your code is trying to achieve, but this version of your code runs:

```
DECLARE
     obj fv_grouping;
BEGIN

   SELECT fv_grouping(cast(collect(fv_group(fv, 3)) as fv_group_array))
   into obj
   from  cophir;

   dbms_output.put_line(obj.which_group(2)) ;

END; 
/
```

This uses COLLECT to gather the `fv_group` objects into an `fv_group_array` instance which can be used to instantiate `fv_grouping` and populate the `obj` variable.

Comment: Thanks ... 
I do need to call the functions of the UDT in the select-from-where-gb clause too. How could I make it? Is it possible?

Comment: You'd have to wrap my query above in an outer query and reference the member functions there. If you cannot figure it out, please **edit your question** to include more details.

Comment: I have edited the question ... hope you can help. 
I need to populate a VArray not only one object. I need to do it in a query, like I have represented in the question. Do u think it is possible?